# How to deal with commits from different development environments?

Tags: c++, git, cmake, cross-platform, project

I decided to convert my Visual Studio project to CMake to develop on multiple platforms. But I wonder how to effectively apply versioning to a CMake project.

Say, from the CMake project I generated a Visual Studio project on Windows, and set up a make file on Linux. I don't want to include those platform specific files in commits. Is it best practice to exclude all those files using `.gitignore`?

This is what first came to my mind, and I would like to know if this is how its done right. For example, I could also include projects for all different platforms in my repository.

Comment: Even better, build "out-of-tree".  Create a new directory, either as a subdirectory or as a sibling, and run cmake from there.  Then all your project files stay clear of your source.  For more fun, you can have multiple build directories for different configurations.

Comment: @Peter That are interesting thoughts, thanks for that. You seem to have experience with cross platform development. Could you elaborate on that or give me resources for diving into deeper, please?

Comment: Try the CMake FAQ: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Out-of-source_build_trees, and this random page, the section on "Building with CMake": http://web.cs.swarthmore.edu/~adanner/tips/cmake.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you use CMake as a base project file, by all means do not add the generated files to the repository. They're effectively useless as a shared thing and often very computer-specific.

As said in the comments (by @Peter, which I shamelessly copy here for better visibility), it is often a good idea to build outside your source tree (unlike the default behavior of Visual Studio). Basically, you do (from the source directory)

```
cd ..
mkdir project-build && cd project-build
cmake ../project
```

You can tell CMake to use a specific "generator" with the `-G` commandline option. Check its help output for details. You can also do this through CMake's GUI.